# Why is my backup file larger than the capacity of all backed up hard drives?

Tags: windows-7, backup

I have 3 hard drives that I regularly back up. Their sizes are: 500 GB, 1TB, and 1TB. When I run backup and restore with an 8TB disk I use for backup I surprisingly find that the harddrive is almost full. How can 2.5TB of media occupy nearly 8TB? How exactly does Windows backup operate?

Is each backup a snapshot of the full 2.5TB each time I run Backup and Restore? What's going on exactly?

[image: Hard Disks]
[image: Backup and Restore running]

Comment: are you sure there aren’t other files on the 8TB disc that take up most of the space? Or perhaps backups from previous days/weeks?

Comment: Do old backups get deleted when new backups get made? Are the backups full, differential, or incremental?

Comment: Windows backups maintain multiple copies of documents that change over time.

Answer (score 1):

Bottom line it appears Window has this notion of ***backup periods*** that seems consistent with what Frank Thomas commented above. Seemingly a file can be backed up multiple times across a set of backup periods.

---

So it looks like when the disk filled up there was this option to `Check backup disk space` with its `Options` button.
[image: Screenshot check backup disk space]

The next window that displays is the `Manage Windows Backup disk space: Select how disk space is used by Windows Backup` which gives you a summary of how much space occupies the data file backup, any system images, and other files you happen to have on the disk.
[image: Screenshot Manage Windows Backup disk space]

Then when you click on the `View backups` button under the section

> Data file backup: You can free up disk space by deleting data file backups

You will find the following view with a table presenting each backup period and its size:

> **Select a backup period to delete**
>
> Deleting previous backups will free up space on your backup location. All files backed up during the selected period will be deleted.

[image: Screenshot select a backup period to delete]

I'll look into running some backup experiments to see how changes through time get captured across these backup periods.

---

Cataloguing here some references for this notion of "*backup periods*"

- https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-performance/windows-7-backup-periods/31447302-bb9a-46da-a684-a5b1eb27b9c6?msgId=bd26eb7d-6f41-4f0e-a21c-a8a83d60a9f8&page=2
- https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/50f3ff7a-2ae7-41c1-ac92-41edaed1e2f9/windows7-backup-not-doing-incremental?forum=w7itprogeneral
- http://codydunne.blogspot.com/2010/10/fullincremental-backup-cutoff-in.html